# PresentViewController With ModalPresentationStyle "UIModalPresentationFormSheet" IOS 8

Tags: ios8, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am not able to set frame to PesentViewController with ModalPresentationStyle `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` in IOS 8. Same code works perfect in IOS 7. For all other ModalPresentationStyle, i am able to set frame. I am doing migration work from IOS 7 to IOS 8. If it is a IOS 8 bug i need a reference to produce.

```
FirstViewController *saleNotApprovedController = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

saleNotApprovedController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;


[self presentViewController:saleNotApprovedController animated:YES completion:^{

      saleNotApprovedController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 500, 500);


}];
```

I tried to set frame in **viewWillLayoutSubviews** For PesentViewController. This code works while loading the page but when we change the  orientation PesentViewController align to centre automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use preferredContentSize to set view's frame.